# How to mock a third party Assembly (XNA/MonoGame) in c#

Tags: xna, mocking, tdd, monogame

So, I've started playing around with MonoGame, and one of the things I have noticed is that it will be really hard to unit test it.

I *could* use something like shims in microsoft fakes but as this blog points out http://blog.pluralsight.com/vs11-fakes-framework, it's not really the TDD way.

I could also use something like Duck Typing which is perfect for everything bar the static methods, but there are a *huge* number of static methods...

I could write adapters for everything, and I'm doing that currently but I've spent a huge amount of time writing adapters and very little writing actual code, which is frustrating.

Final option I can think of is generating the adapters, which seems like a reasonable idea, except I can't find any tool to do it, I mean I'm happy enough to write something that does it, but it seems like one of those problems that has probably been solved already in a better way.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately XNA was a pretty terrible design when it comes to unit testing. You can blame Microsoft for that. I'm also interested in any answers to this question.

Comment: There really doesn't seem to be anything out there that solves this problem, will just have to start an open source project to solve it. Here is the github https://github.com/evalacy/AdapterPatternGenerator

Answer (score 1):

The general advice is "don't mock what you don't own" and write adapters that you can mock for unit testing your code and a few integration tests for the adapters and the third party code. Usually you try to keep adapters as thin as possible, but in the case where your code depends on many entry points in the third party code, forcing you to write many adapters, it may be worthwhile to look for an intermediate abstraction that your code depends on, that can be implemented by a few adapters that are a bit "thicker", i.e., that are not 1:1 with the third-party code, but provide some higher-level functions.